# Overloading ++ operator

Tags: c++

I need to overload operators for a class of complex numbers 
with 2 private members :

```
    double real;
    double imag;
```

this is the constructor

```
complex::complex(double a, double b) {
    real = a;
    imag = b;
}
```

This is the given prototype

```
complex complex :: operator++ (int x);
```

but I don't see how this would be overwritten since

```
int u = 1;
int h = 3;

u++3;
```

doesn't work

so how would this compile

I've only ever seen

```
variable++

--variable
```

How would this be overloaded?

Comment: The `+=` operator also exists

Comment: Note that `++` operation does not have well-defined semantics for complex numbers. Therefore, it is advisable to avoid implementing it at all.

Answer (score 4):

The `int x` in the post-increment operator signature `operator++(int x)` is called a *dummy parameter*. It doesn't actually mean anything, other than to distinguish this from `operator++()` which is the pre-increment operator.

In the body of the function you write the logic for post-increment but just don't use `x`. It gets value `0` when you use `variable++`.

Technically you could write `variable.operator++(5);` and then the post-increment operator would be called with `x` being `5` but there's no real reason to want to do that.